# How do i check if the script is executing in editor mode or runtime mode?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class SliderManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    public GameObject[] Objects = new GameObject[100];
    public GameObject Model;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        SetSlider((int)slider.value);
    }

    protected void SetSlider(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Objects.Length; i++)
        {
            bool mustBeAnObject = i < x;

            if ((mustBeAnObject) && (Objects[i] == null))
                Objects[i] = Instantiate(Model);
            else if ((!mustBeAnObject) && (Objects[i] != null))
            {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                DestroyImmediate(Objects[i]);
#else
                
#endif
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the [ExecuteAlways] to run the code in both editor mode and runtime mode.
the problem is in the bottom when i'm using Destroy i need to check if it's in editor mode to use DestroyImmediate and if in runtime to use Destroy.

i tried to use #if UNITY_EDITOR but not sure how to continue with it and if to use that way or to use:

```
if(Application.isPlaying)
```

and also, as a side question, should i use the attribute [ExecuteAlways] or should i make another Editor type script?

a bit messed.

Comment: `Application.isPlaying` seems like what you want - did you run into any specific difficulty making this work with that?

Comment: @DMGregory this part is working fine but for some reason now the whole script is not working and it did before.  for some reason the Objects array is all the time length 0 even if i set it to have length 100. i didn't change anything.

Comment: @DMGregory i found that if i put this line in the Start Objects = new GameObject[100]; the array length is 100 but the Start function is not executing in editor mode.  then where should i initi the array when in editor mode ?

Comment: Did you try making it a field initializer?

Comment: @DMGregory i did try : public GameObject[] Objects = new GameObject[100]; but it didn't work the array length is 0.

Comment: Do you have an instance of this script that has a value assigned to this field in the inspector already? Once such a value exists, it won't be overwritten by the initializer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is:

```
Application.isPlaying == true // you are not in editor mode
Application.isPlaying == false // you are in editor mode
```

As for your other questions:

ExecuteInEditMode is limited and does not call all the functions of the MonoBehaviour as it would when running in PlayMode.

It also doesn't work well when the MonoBehaviour is in a prefab and in the Prefab editor.

There are good reasons to use ExecuteInEditMode if it works for what you need, but if you can refactor your code to use Editor scripts it will give you more power and control over your ability to write good manipulators and editor tools.

Things like "Undo" and marking objects dirty so the scene manager knows it needs to save.

Comment: i will try to work with editor script. i  will create editor script for the mono one and will work with it.

Answer (score 0):

The Application.IsPlaying (obsolete) will return true even in the editor.
To know if you are in editor, use Application.IsEditor.
false means runtime, true means editor.
At least since version 2019
Regards,
Robert

Comment: If you read the question, you'll see that they want to know whether they should call Destroy() (play mode - standalone OR in editor) or DestroyImmediate() (edit mode in editor). Application.IsPlaying correctly makes that distinction. Application.isEditor is useful for determining "am I running in editor or standalone?" but that's not the distinction being asked about here, despite the confusing phrasing.